# CKEditor's SetData doesn't work in version 4 -

Tags: jquery, html, ckeditor

I'm in the process of upgrading to CKEditor version 4.5.8. I use jQuery to access the CKEditor API.

The textarea of the editor doesn't update. Is there a config option I need to set?

Html:

```
<textarea name="mck_1" id="mck_1"> Enter text. </textarea>
<script> CKEDITOR.replace( 'mck_1' ); </script>
```

Javascript:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.mck_1.setData("Hello");
```

How do I debug this?  Do I have to explicitly update the display/textarea?

If I try to manually update the textarea in Firebug,  it says "undefined".

```
CKEDITOR.instances.mck_1.setData("hi");
undefined
```

There are a lot of "setData not working" questions for past versions of CKEditor in StackOverflow but none of the suggested solutions there work for me.

Help!

MMiz

EDIT: I realized the first "setData" on the textarea actually works. It's the second one that follows that does not display. From this [thread](http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Second-Time-jQuery-Doesnt-Work)

[1](http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Second-Time-jQuery-Doesnt-Work): http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Second-Time-jQuery-Doesnt-Work it seems like there is some timing thing. But that's as far as I've gotten.

Comment: why you make it so complex and where the editor id , and what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: @noni - I'm trying to programmatically input data into the editor using jQuery. The id of the editor is "mck_1".

Comment: Where are you calling setData? Perhaps it's before the textarea has been converted to a ckeditor instance? For testing, add a button on your page with its onclick event set to `CKEDITOR.instances.mck_1.setData('Hello')` and see what happens when you click the button after the editor has fully loaded.

Comment: @Atzmon - I check to see that ckeditor is loaded before writing into it. I just noticed an odd thing - if I  "getData" on the textarea after my seemingly failed "setData" it returns the updated text "hi". So, it's just not displaying the updated text.  Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @user1072910 Sorry, no idea. This may be a problem specific to your implementation so if you post a stripped down bare bones working example of your code, maybe someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out the answer was in the CKEditor documentation (yeah I know - RTFM first). The underlying cause for this behavior is that setData method is asynchronous and so you need to code accordingly.

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-setData

Quote: "Note that this method is asynchronous. The callback parameter must be used if interaction with the editor is needed after setting the data."

In my case since I'm trying to setData twice in a row, I definitely need to have a callback. It now works.

Comment: In my case I was trying to set the editor contents to null using setData(), which wasn't working. It turns out I had to pass an empty string instead.

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently using ckeditor5 and non of the above answers worked for me.
Based on the [document](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/faq.html#how-to-get-the-editor-instance-object-from-the-dom-element) you can manipulate the inner html of ckeditor with this lines of code:

```
// A reference to the editor editable element in the DOM.
const domEditableElement = document.querySelector( '.ck-editor__editable' );

// Get the editor instance from the editable element.
const editorInstance = domEditableElement.ckeditorInstance;

// Use the editor instance API.
editorInstance.setData( '<p>Hello world!<p>' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('textarea').each(function () {
   var $textarea = $(this);
   CKEDITOR.instances[$textarea.attr('name')].setData($textarea.val());
});
```

instaed of getting the data from ckeditor and setting back to editor make use of textarea and iterate and get all data and set to each ckeditor,,,before iterate create a instance of CKEDITOR

Answer (score 0):

This -> http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-setData

Replace:

`CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.updateElement();`

With:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].setData(response, {
                    callback: function() {
                    this.checkDirty(); // true
                    }
                } );
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
initData="<p>Hello from CKEditor 4!</p>"
```

this link has more info:

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_react_current.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.